# How to integrate a component in a Joomla template?

Tags: component, templates, positions

If we need ton integrate a module in a template, we add this code in the index.php :

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-4')): ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="xhtml" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

But how can we integrate a component ?

I’ve installed a module that appears in the component menu and i don’t see any module position there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The define the area where a component is displayed, you need to add the following somewhere in your template index.php:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Do bare in mind that this should only be used **once**

For more information in `jdoc include` statements, have a read of the following:

http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements

Hope this helps

Comment: Perfect, it works. So in a template, if i need a component on a specific page, i need to link a menu item to the component and add this code in the template with a condition to check the id of the menu item ?

Comment: No, this is where the dynamic side kicks in. The template index.php is only used to define where you want to display things. If you want a component on a specific page, simply create a new menu item in the Joomla backend and set the **type** to which ever component you wish to use

Comment: Yes, i know how to do that. I’m creating a template from scratch and i need a specific design for a component. I was wondering how to integrate it in index.php According to your comment, i only need <jdoc:include type="component" /> once. I think i need to review my template structure.

Comment: Ahh I see. In this case you should create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)